# How to get rid of italic in the table of contents?

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, formatting

I formatted the titles of section and subsections in *italic*, and it appears *italic* in the Table of Contents, I want no influence on the Table of Contents. For example

```
\subsection{\textit{The RGE for the $SU(N)$ Chern-Simons free energy}}
```

this will appear in the Table of Contents in *italics*:

> *The RGE for the SU(N) Chern-Simons free energy*

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The [`sectsty`](http://ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) or [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlsec) package can help with this. It is preferred to use a package, for the sake of consistency.

Comment: Also http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5326/29410 would work in your case.