# error when using \tableofcontents

Tags: table-of-contents

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno,a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\textheight 9.3in \textwidth 6.5in
\calclayout
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[subsection]
\newtheorem*{question}{Question}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newcommand{\mc}{\mathcal}
\newcommand{\mf}{\mathfrak}
\newtheorem*{solution}{Solution}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise} 
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{datetime}
% \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2} 
\usepackage{color}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\newcommand{\xra}{\xrightarrow}
\newcommand{\ra}{\rightarrow}
\title{A}
\author{B} 

\begin{document}
    \today
\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract} 

\maketitle 
\tableofcontents 
\section{asdsd}
\subsection{A $p\colon \underline{X}\ra \mc{D}$B} 

\end{document}
```

When I do not run \tableofcontents, I see no problem. If I run \tableofcontents, I see

```
line 3: Missing $ inserted. ...htarrow \mathcal {D}$B}}{2}{subsection.1.1}
line 3: Missing $ inserted. ...htarrow \mathcal {D}$B}}{2}{subsection.1.1}
: It is better to use one of the extsizes classes, if you can.
line 48: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref) removing `math shift'
line 48: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref) removing `\mskip'
line 48: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref) removing `\mathpunct'
line 48: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref) removing `\nonscript'
line 48: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref) removing `\mkern'
line 48: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref) removing `\thinmuskip'
line 48: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref) removing `\mskip'
line 48: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref) removing `math shift'
line 48: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref) removing `\@@underline'
line 48: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref) removing `\hbox'
line 48: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref) removing `\mathsurround'
line 48: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref) removing `\z@'
line 48: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref) removing `math shift'
line 48: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref) removing `\rightarrow'
line 48: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref) removing `math shift'
: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.
```

In above, first two came as errors in red font. It is mentioned as file document.toc Third is as a  warning. It is mentioned as file extsizes.sty

Everything else came as warnings in the file document.tex

Comment: How is the full title of the first subsection that causes this problem?

Comment: @Jonathan  I have added the title

Comment: Probably unrelated, but `hyperref` should (in most cases) be loaded last. Apart from that, [Equations in section heading/title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5314/134144)  might be interesting.

Comment: Thanks for adding the title. It works fine for me. Can you try to remove all auxiliary files and compile again? If this does not work, can you make a demo document, that replicates the error?

Comment: @Jonathan I have added the demo document. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by using `\underline` in the subsection title, it can be solved by adding `\protect` in front of it. In addition all the warnings about `Token not allowed in a PDF string` can be avoided by providing an alternative text for the bookmarks:

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno,a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\textheight 9.3in \textwidth 6.5in
\calclayout
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[subsection]
\newtheorem*{question}{Question}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newcommand{\mc}{\mathcal}
\newcommand{\mf}{\mathfrak}
\newtheorem*{solution}{Solution}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise} 
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{datetime}
% \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2} 
\usepackage{color}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\newcommand{\xra}{\xrightarrow}
\newcommand{\ra}{\rightarrow}
\title{A}
\author{B} 

\begin{document}
    \today
\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract} 

\maketitle 
\tableofcontents 
\section{asdsd}
\subsection{A \texorpdfstring{$p\colon \protect\underline{X} \ra \mc{D} $}{alternative text for bookmarks}B} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I do not understand what is a bookmark?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Bookmarks are the what your pdfviewers shows at the left besides the actual document where you can navigate between the different sections. This stuff: https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/page-thumbnails-bookmarks-pdfs/_jcr_content/main-pars/image_1.img.png/ed03.png