# Add math stuff into beamer section

Tags: beamer, math-mode, sectioning

So here's a minimal code:

```
\documentclass[utf8]{beamer}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}

\begin{document}
    \section{$\frac{a}{b}$}
\end{document}
```

I tried the solution from this answer:
[Equations in section heading/title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5314/equations-in-section-heading-title)

But it doesn't work either:

```
\documentclass[utf8]{beamer}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}

\begin{document}
    \section{\texorpdfstring{$\frac{a}{b}$}}
\end{document}
```

This is the error message:

```
! Argument of \@firstoftwo has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.6     \section{\texorpdfstring{$\frac{a}{b}$}}
```

Do you have an idea how I can add an little math environment into the sections?

Comment: `\textorpdfstrig` expects *two* arguments: first the TeX-related one, then the pdf bookmark one. You need e.g. `\texorpdfstring{$\frac{a}{b}$}{a/b}`.

Comment: Oh bruh, I didn't knew that. Thank you! Could you please write that as an answer so I can tick this questions as `answered`?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because itwas solved in the comments.